# how do i design a custom layout in latex?

Tags: graphics

I have to prepare a report and it was given to me a Microsoft Word template. But my report will be full of math, cross references etc, so i would not like to write it using word but LaTex. My question is, how could i reproduce this layout with latex:

**Some info about the project:**

[image]

**The structure of a \part{}** (The report with chapters will be put mainly in this table-cell-like-structure, every blank page would be surrounded by the limits of such cell)

[image]

Any sugestions?

Comment: Could you post some code to show what you have tried so far? Then users here can help you with the difficult parts.

Comment: Have a look at the [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package.

Comment: As Benjamin said: `tcolorbox` package, but perhaps in conjunction with the `background` package

Comment: Hi there, welcome to TeX.sx! `:)` In my humble opinion, you actually need to know beforehand if IF (and CNPq for that matter) is allowed to take formats other than MS Word. I know at least Fapesp is, to some extent, quite feral with their forms.

Comment: I usually auto-convert this kind of thing and then clean it up gradually if I use the form more than once. (wvware) But it doesn't give clean code, for sure.